# How do I find a Magento products primary category

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am using Magento 1.6.2.

I need to find an easy way of checking which category is the "default" category for any given product, where multiple categories have been assigned to that product.

The reason for this is as follows:
I have different discount amounts available on different categories in my store.
Where a product falls into two categories with different discounts applied, the highest discount should be applied to that product, but if that product has been added to the system (created) with a default category that has a lower discount, and then afterwards added into the higher discount category as well, the higher discount level is not being applied when that product is purchased.
If, however, I add the product to the higher discount category first, and then to the lower discount category afterwards (so the product appears on my website in all the right places), the correct (higher) discount level applies to that product.

I can only assume, therefore, that the default (or primary, or first, however you want to label it) category is the one that determines the outcome of the discount level to be applied to it. If this is wrong, then I need a lesson in understanding the mechanics behind this to see where I have gone wrong in the overall setup of this system...

If my assumption is correct, then I need a way to determine which category any given product (using the SKU) has been assigned to first, to ensure that the correct discount can be applied to that product.

I hope I have explained that clearly enough!
Does anyone have any suggestions. I have been unable to find information on this regardless of guessing specific search terms. The only things I can find are related to general category retrieval, and not this very specific task I need.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid your assumption is incorrect. Magento has no concept of a 'primary' category for a product. It only knows the product is in category id(s);

```
1, 12, 234
```

etc.  The id's are stored numercially with no idea of which category might be more important than another.

What you could do instead is create a custom attribute and enter the id of the category you want to treat as 'primary' and retreive this attribute value when working out whether to give more discount or not.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I understand what you are saying, but in practice this doesn't quite add up. When I create the product, it gets created with just 1 category first, in a separate system. Once the product is uploaded to Magento, I can then edit the product and add more categories. If I put the product into category A first, and then add category B second, the discount applied is based on Category A. If I reverse that process, then the discount applied is based on Category B. I just want to figure out exactly how this works if at all possible.

Comment: Adding an attribute would then require me to go through my entire catalogue (35,000 products) manually - not going to happen... :-)

Comment: that sounds more like your discount is not being applied correctly. If you have 10% off products in category A and 15% off products incategory B, that should hold true regardless of which way around you add the products to the category. Perhaps you are adding them from outside the category?  in a latest product module or similar?  For managing a new attribute, presumably your external system knows the main category?.  Check out Magmi, you can import 35k products (once you setup the csv) in minutes.  1 of the sites i manage has 60k products & 20 store views. Magmi allows easy management.

Comment: **perhaps you are adding the products to the basket from outside of the category  << is what i meant

Comment: Not adding products to basket - just simply viewing the product details page, where the discounted price is displayed. If product was added to category A first, then cat B second, the discount amount is Category A level. If it is added to cat B first, then the discount amount is Category B level. It seems to me that it looks for which categories a product is in, and stops at the first one it finds, and applies that discount level. I can't see what else would cause this behaviour?